# WPF ViewModel running method in another thread, reporting progress, changing Button's IsEnabled and displaying result

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm

I am trying to find a proper way of running existing methods using threads created in the ViewModel. The main purpose is to provide a responsive UI. I decided I want to use the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern, but I need to properly integrate it with WPF and MVVM.

So far, I found a way to run a lengthy task in another thread and report its progress. However, I couldn't find a way of updating the Button that starts the task so that it IsEnabled only when the task is not running. The following ViewModel describes what I have done:

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // Do some time consuming work.
    int SomeTask()
    {
        //SCENARIO: Consider that it takes longer than usual to start the worker thread.
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        // Prevent executing the task by two threads at the same time.
        lock ("IsReady")
        {
            if (IsReady == false)
                throw new ApplicationException("Task is already running");
            IsReady = false;
        }

        // The actual work that this task consists of.
        TaskProgress = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(50);
            TaskProgress = i;
        }

        // Mark task as completed to allow rerunning it.
        IsReady = true;

        return 123;
    }

    // True when not started or completed.
    bool _isReady = true;
    public bool IsReady
    {
        get { return _isReady; }
        set
        {
            _isReady = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("IsReady");
            StartTaskCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }

    // Indicate the current progress when running SomeTask.
    int _taskProgress;
    public int TaskProgress
    {
        get { return _taskProgress; }
        set
        {
            _taskProgress = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TaskProgress");
        }
    }

    // ICommand to start task asynchronously.
    RelayCommand _startTask;
    public RelayCommand StartTaskCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_startTask == null)
            {
                _startTask = new RelayCommand(
                    obj =>
                    {
                        Task<int> task = Task.Run((Func<int>)SomeTask);
                        task.ContinueWith(t =>
                        {
                            // SomeTask method may throw an ApplicationException.
                            if (!t.IsFaulted)
                                Result = t.Result.ToString();
                        });
                    },
                    obj => IsReady);

            }
            return _startTask;
        }
    }

    string _result;
    public string Result
    {
        get { return _result; }
        set { _result = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Result"); }
    }
}
```

I use the following implementation of RelayCommand:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> execute;
    private Func<object, bool> canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        this.execute = execute;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return this.canExecute == null || this.canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this.execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

The main problem is that the Button that executes the command does not update its status based on `IsReady`. I also tried setting it explicitly with `IsEnabled="{Binding IsReady}"`, but it still doesn't work. The best article I found related to this problem is this one: [Raising CanExecuteChanged](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/31f10685-25fc-4acd-a4a6-0b316505e9ba/raising-canexecutechanged?forum=wpf).

The XAML is quite simple:

```
<DockPanel Margin="4">
    <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Right" Text="{Binding Result}" Width="100"/>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="Start" Margin="5,0"
            Command="{Binding StartTaskCommand}"/>
    <ProgressBar Value="{Binding TaskProgress}"/>
</DockPanel>
```

How do I fix IsReady to be reflected by the Button's state?

Does anyone recommend a minimalistic working implementation for what I need?

Thanks for taking your time to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `IsReady` property to `false` on the UI thread before you start the task, and then set it back to `true` once the task has completed:

```
public RelayCommand StartTaskCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_startTask == null)
        {
            _startTask = new RelayCommand(
                obj =>
                {
                    if (IsReady)
                    {
                        //1. Disable the button on the UI thread
                        IsReady = false;
                        //2. Execute SomeTask on a background thread
                        Task.Factory.StartNew(SomeTask)
                        .ContinueWith(t =>
                        {
                            //3. Enable the button back on the UI thread
                            if (!t.IsFaulted)
                                Result = t.Result.ToString();
                            IsReady = true;
                        }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
                    }
                },
                obj => IsReady);

        }
        return _startTask;
    }
}

int SomeTask()
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    TaskProgress = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        TaskProgress = i;
    }

    return 123;
}
```

Comment: This is a more elegant way of getting rid of the lock("IsSelected") because the IsReady property is set before the thread is created. There is one small problem, the button doesn't enable back when finished. Am I missing something? I checked in the debugger and indeed IsReady is set to true from the Main Thread.

Comment: Is the getter of the IsReady property invoked after you set the IsReady property to true in ContinueWith?

Comment: Yes it is. It's called by NotifyPropertyChanged, also from Main Thread. Am I dizzy?

Comment: It is called after VS switches instantly to MainWindow and back again, so I guess it's due to change of focus on the window. I tried with and without `IsEnabled="{Binding IsReady}"`. It's not working either ways.

Comment: How is VS related to this? Does it work as expected if you run it without the debugger attached?

Comment: You shouldn't combine CanExecute with binding to the IsEnabled property.

Comment: Setting the IsReady property and raise the PropertyChanged event should definitely update IsEnabled if you do bind it though.

Comment: I noticed `StartTaskCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` was commented in IsReady setter. It works if I put it back, but it doesn't quite make sense for me. Were you expecting this behavior?

Comment: Yes. You need to raise the CanExecuteChanged of the command whenever you want to "refresh" the status of the Button, i.e. whenever you want the CanExecute method of the command to be called again.

Comment: And yes it works if I bind IsEnabled and delete the canExecute handler.

Comment: Isn't this exactly the same as what async / await does behind the scenes? I mean, continuing with the CurrentSynchronizationContext. Is there any specific reason not to use simply Result = await SomeTask(); instead?

Answer (score 1):

You have to update your IsRady flag on the UI thread. I modify your sample to achieve the expected behavior:

```
int SomeTask()
{


    // Prevent executing the task by two threads at the same time.
    lock ("IsReady")
    {
        if (IsReady == false)
            throw new ApplicationException("Task is already running");
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { IsReady = false; });
    }

    //SCENARIO: Consider that it takes longer than usual to start the worker thread.
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    // The actual work that this task consists of.
    TaskProgress = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        TaskProgress = i;
    }

    // Mark task as completed to allow rerunning it.
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { IsReady = true; });

    return 123;
}
```

You were firing PropertyChanged event from other thread, that was the problem.

I put also the thread sleeping below the lock since I was getting your ApplicationExceptions lol

**EDIT**

Since you are raising canExecuteChanged you could solve this also by raising that event on the UI thread:

```
 public bool IsReady
        {
            get { return _isReady; }
            set
            {
                _isReady = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsReady");
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    StartTaskCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged(); 
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Indeed that was the problem. I tried to refactor your magic code to `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => NotifyPropertyChanged("IsReady"))` in order to use it once in IsReady setter, but it doesn't work. Any idea why? Also, I can't figure it out why TaskProgress doesn't encounter this problem and works fine.

Comment: @MatrixRonny, sorry, I was thinking button's IsEnabled was bound, but instead you are rasing canExecuteChanged from the setter. I have edited the answer to show an alternative solution

Comment: Yes, I came up with the same IsReady version. One more thing, is there an easier way if I bind `IsEnabled="{Binding IsReady}"`? I read that InvalidateRequerySuggested, that I use in RaiseCanExecuteChanged, is quite a costly operation.